# How to find point in intersects plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, plane-geometry

Find the point at which the line x = 3-t ,y = -3t, z = 1-2t intersects the plane x+y-2z = 2 .

How to solve this question?

Is it only replace the x, y and z ?

Answer (score 0):

plugging $$x=3-t,y=-3t,z=1-2t$$ in the equation of the given plane we get
$$3-t-3t-2(1-2t)=2$$
now solve this equation for $t$
we will find no real $t$ thus your line doesn't intersect the plane
the line is parallel to the plane

Comment: so the answer is 0 ?

Comment: I know it's 2 years later... Is there any algorithm to get the point for any plane and any line? (In case they aren't parallel)